# How to setup PROGUARD for Jackson JSON Processor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, jackson, proguard

I am using Jackson JSON Processor for my app.Included this using

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'.
```

And my proguard configuration is.

```
## BEGIN -- Google Play Services proguard.txt
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}
# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}
# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
## END -- Google Play Services proguard.txt

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-keepattributes *Annotation*.
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.**




-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.android.BuildConfig
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.**
```

However when i try to compile in debug mode i get the following error.

```
26207-26207/com.blah E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blah, PID: 26207
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:290)
            at com.b.a.c.f.ah.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.b.a.c.z.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.blah.utils.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.blah.main.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.blah.main.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.blah.main.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

Working on it for a long time!Would appreciate your help!Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

After much debugging finally found the answer my Proguard configuration is

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
}
```

your class depicts the getter setter classes/class you are using to parse your response.

Also I added `compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'`
to my Gradle file which was missing previously. Now my Proguard works like a beast..;-)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the Signature flag in -keepattributes that finally made my ProGuard settings work.

Answer (score 5):

Modified a litte from @goonerDroid work for me

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`keep enum ** { *; }` is enough for me. I don't know why however.