# Android APK Crash with ProGuard and JSON

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, proguard

I’ve exported my LibGDX project as an Android APK with ProGuard and when running it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) it crashes on startup.

From what I can tell, the problem appears to be a combination of using ProGruard and trying to load in previously saved data from a JSON file. Every time the program exits it saves the current state of the program to the JSON file and when the program is started up again it reads the data from the JSON file and resets the program to previous state.

The program doesn’t crash when running it from within Eclipse (since ProGuard is not used then) and I’m not sure how to obtain a crash log from the APK installed on my phone...which is making this much harder to troubleshoot. But I have determined:

- The crash does not occur if the APK is created with ProGuard disabled.
- The crash also does not occur if ProGuard is enabled, but I bypass loading data from the JSON file and instead just use default values.

Here is my code:

**Logic.java**

```
public class Logic{
    private RecallLastPreferences recall;
    public DataMain dataMain;

    public Logic(){
        //. . .
        recall = new RecallLastPreferences(this);
        dataMain = recall.loadPreferences();
        //. . .
    }
}
```

**RecallLastPreferences.java**

```
public class RecallLastPreferences {
    private Logic logic;    
    private SaveManager saveManager;

    public RecallLastPreferences(Logic logic){
        this.logic = logic;
        saveManager = new SaveManager();
    }

    public void savePreferences(){      
        saveManager.saveDataValue("main", logic.dataMain);
    }

    public <T> T loadPreferences(){
        return saveManager.loadDataValue("main", DataMain.class);
    }
}
```

**SaveManager.java**

```
public class SaveManager {
    private ObjectMap<String, Object> data = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
    private FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("save.json");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SaveManager(){
        if(file.exists()){
            Json json = new Json();
            data = json.fromJson(ObjectMap.class, file.readString());
        }
    }

    private void saveToJson(){
        Json json = new Json();
        json.setOutputType(OutputType.json);
        file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(data), false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T loadDataValue(String key, Class<?> type){      
        if(data.containsKey(key)){
            return (T)data.get(key);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void saveDataValue(String key, Object object){
        data.put(key, object);
        saveToJson();
    }

    public ObjectMap<String, Object> getAllData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

**proguard-project.txt**

```
-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
    <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
    boolean contactFilter(long, long);
    void    beginContact(long);
    void    endContact(long);
    void    preSolve(long, long);
    void    postSolve(long, long);
    boolean reportFixture(long);
    float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't crash when running from Eclipse only when I create the APK with ProGuard and install it directly to my phone...and I don't know how to get the crash log (or logcat) in this case. I tried installing an app on my phone to show the log and another that sent the log to my email, but I couldn't find any logs/errors related to my program. This is part of what is making this such a difficult problem for me to debug. Do you know of a way I can get the locgcat error in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687128/how-to-setup-proguard-for-jackson-json-processor

Comment: Lionel Port, I hadn't seen that before, but I'm using LibGDX (as well as the JSON writer that's included with LibGDX) so my ProGuard file looks completely different. I edited my original post to include my proguard-project file as well, so maybe that will help shine some light on my problem. Thanks.